# Running node subprocess from a python script in heroku server

Tags: python, heroku

I'm running `node module` in python script using `subprocess.check_call()`, it is running locally,I'm getting issue while deploying it to heroku server , Is there any way to run `npm` module in heroku server?

Comment: _Specifically_, what does "I'm getting issue while deploying it to heroku server" mean? What kind of issue? What error messages are you getting? Please read [ask].

Comment: Error message is node module name is not defined 
example : subprocess.check_call( node module name ) .
I want to know how to install node module in the heroku server inorder to run in the python script.